# NTLM Authentication on Symfony 2

Tags: internet-explorer, symfony, single-sign-on, ntlm, intranet

I'm actually building an intranet with Symfony 2 and I have to log automatically users (I mean no login form...).. For the moment, I'm using a method from my controller which change headers to launch NTLM Authentication on the browser. It works well but after the user is logged in, he can't send any POST form : all values are empty. All those problems are on Internet Explorer, on Firefox and Chrome it's okay. For using this method, i had to set KeepAlive at On in my Apache configuration to make it work on Internet Explorer.

I use this code to get the user login via NTLM :

```
public function getInfos() {

    $headers = apache_request_headers();
    $infos = array();

    if (!isset($headers['Authorization'])) {
        header('HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized');
        header('WWW-Authenticate: NTLM');
        exit;
    }

    $auth = $headers['Authorization'];

    if (substr($auth, 0, 5) == 'NTLM ') {
        $msg = base64_decode(substr($auth, 5));
        if (substr($msg, 0, 8) != "NTLMSSP\x00")
            die('error header not recognised');

        if ($msg[8] == "\x01") {
            $msg2 = "NTLMSSP\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00" .
                    "\x00\x00\x00\x00" . // target name len/alloc
                    "\x00\x00\x00\x00" . // target name offset
                    "\x01\x02\x81\x00" . // flags
                    "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00" . // challenge
                    "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00" . // context
                    "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"; // target info len/alloc/offset

            header('HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized');
            header('WWW-Authenticate: NTLM ' . trim(base64_encode($msg2)));
            exit;
        } else if ($msg[8] == "\x03") {

            function get_msg_str($msg, $start, $unicode = true) {
                $len = (ord($msg[$start + 1]) * 256) + ord($msg[$start]);
                $off = (ord($msg[$start + 5]) * 256) + ord($msg[$start + 4]);
                if ($unicode)
                    return str_replace("\0", '', substr($msg, $off, $len));
                else
                    return substr($msg, $off, $len);
            }

            $user = get_msg_str($msg, 36);
            $domain = get_msg_str($msg, 28);
            $workstation = get_msg_str($msg, 44);

            $infos = array('login' => $user, 'domaine' => $domain, 'machine' => $workstation);
        }
    }
    return $infos;
}
```

I've looked for an other way but for those who works on Symfony : issues are too old, so If you have an idea how to solve this problem or another better and cleaner way to do this with Symfony.

Comment: do you want basic http authentication popup ? what do you mean by login user automatically ? To authenticate user has to tell who he/she is ? There are many authentication mechanisms in symfony security (basic http, form login etc)

Answer (score 2):

Sorry to answer this old question, but as I faced the same issue, i'm sharing some clues for future lads :

The IE thing about NTLM authentification and empty POST is a feature (!) to avoid network unnecessary load :

When some element on the page have needed NTLM handshake, IE assumes that all future requests (on domain scope) will need NTLM authent... In order to preserve network, IE will send only the POST content on the third round of the expected handshake.
If your app does not trigger this authent, the POST content is never sent.

This is explained in detail (and with better words than mine)  here : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2010/11/22/internet-explorer-post-bodies-are-zero-bytes-in-length-when-authentication-challenges-are-expected.aspx.

To solve your case, yo'll need to implement the NTLM authent on each calls (or each subsequent calls after the first one is triggered), you can do this using customs Firewalls / Authent providers as drafted in Symfony2 online doc : http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/custom_authentication_provider.html.

As this is not really easy to implement, I'll recommend you to use existing Bundles to focus more on your code than on theses painfull features.

Comment: Well thank you, I looked for that kind of answer for a while but finally, I did it in an other way:
- Downgrading the framework to match with the version required for the bundle recommended by @Paul Andrieux
- Use that bundle for NTLM Authentication :)

Answer (score 1):

Is this bundle do what you want ? 
https://github.com/ecoad/NtlmBundle

It is sf2.0 compilant, so you maybe will have to update it for recent sf version.

Comment: Well. Thank you, since I've downgrade my framework version and adapt it for my problem.